# Opening file within if statement

Tags: c

I have inherited some old C routines that I maintain through a little knowledge.  I'm trying to add some logging into one of the routines which I have done, but I want to be able to turn the logging on and off with a setting in an INI file.  I have also done this, but I need to stop the logfile creation when the logging is turned off.    I'd like it to not create the file in the first place if the logging is off.

If I enable the logging, it all works perfectly.  but if I disable the logging, it creates the file, but doesn't write anything to it.

```
int LOG_ENABLED=FALSE;


... some code here to set LOG_ENABLED to either TRUE or FALSE...


char filename[50];
struct tm * timenow;
time_t now = time(NULL);
timenow = gmtime(&now);
strftime(filename, sizeof(filename), "/logfiles/program1/log/%y%m%d_%H%M%S.log", timenow);


if (LOG_ENABLED == TRUE)
{
    FILE *output_file = fopen(filename, "a");
}
```

When I compile this, it produces many errors, but if I take the 'if' condition out it compiles OK, but still produces me a zero byte logfile.

I'm happy that the LOG_ENABLED is declared OK, as I use it elsewhere in the program to control data being written to the log.

What have I missed?

Thank you.

Comment: `it produces many errors` What are those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the definition outside of that Block:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *file = "/Path/to/file";
    FILE *output_file;
    if ( 1 )
    {
        output_file = fopen( file, "r");
        if ( output_file == NULL )
        {
            printf("Error, deal with...\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    fclose( output_file );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `output_file` is local to the `if` block it is defined in and goes out of scope when you leave the block.  So anyplace after that where you use `output_file` complain that the variable is not defined.

Define `output_file` outside of the `if` block.

```
FILE *output_file = NULL;
if (LOG_ENABLED == TRUE)
{
    output_file = fopen(filename, "a");
}
```

Be sure to either check if `output_file` is set to NULL anyplace you use it later, or set to something like `stdout` so output goes to the console.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good lesson about variable scopes. When you declare a variable inside braces like below, it only exists within that block.

```
if (LOG_ENABLED == TRUE)
{
    FILE *output_file = fopen(filename, "a");
}
```

This isn't much use to you, you want to declare it outside the block and assign it with a value inside the block. Most likely you'd want it declared at a global level so that the entire file has access to it, or at least whatever functions that need to write to the file have access.

```
FILE *output_file = NULL;
if (LOG_ENABLED == TRUE)
{
    output_file = fopen(filename, "a");
}
```

And most likely later when you want to use it you'd have something like

```
if(output_file)
{
     fprintf(output_file,"hello world\n");
}
```